# Can we manually select which satellites to use in solution?

Tags: gps, satellite

For example, I have used below satellites ID in current solution:

```
ID    Signal Strength
______________________
 1         21
22         23
19         12
36         26
20         18
 3         29
32         14
13         15
```

But I want to filter and use only those satellites with **higher signal strength** in my solution, let say `satellite ID: 1, 22, 36, 3`. Is it possible?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about GPS device interaction

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the program you are using but for example with rtklib it is possible by using the excluded/included satellites parameter http://www.rtklib.com/rtklib_tutorial.htm.

Comment: I'm developing my own application for this. But if this `RTKLIB` able to do it, means it is possible. but does it depends on the device?

Comment: Yes, it depends on the device. Rtklib is especially made for real time kinematics and for doing that it needs to get raw data from the GPS receiver. I am not s specialist on this area but rtklib manual is probably interesting reading for you http://www.rtklib.com/prog/manual_2.4.2.pdf.